# Ant with JUnit giving multiple test reports

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have the following target set in my Ant script to generate test reports. It does its job quite well, but what I observe is that, if I have two tests written, I get individual XML file outputs and also a aggregated XML file containing the same information nested inside  tag.

Can anyone tell me how I can avoid this file from being generated?

My relevant ANT target and tests are given below..

```
<target name="test" depends="init,compile">
                <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" showoutput="yes" >
                        <!--
                                Note the classpath order: instrumented classes are before the
                                original (uninstrumented) classes.  This is important.
                        -->
                        <classpath location="${instrumented.dir}" />
                        <classpath location="${classes.dir}" />

                        <!--
                                The instrumented classes reference classes used by the
                                Cobertura runtime, so Cobertura and its dependencies
                                must be on your classpath.
                        -->
                        <classpath refid="cobertura.classpath" />


                        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.xml.dir}">
                                <formatter type="xml" />
                                <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                                        <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
                                </fileset>
                        </batchtest>
                </junit>

                <junitreport todir="${reports.xml.dir}">
                        <fileset dir="${reports.xml.dir}">
                                <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
                        </fileset>
                </junitreport>
        </target>
```

//TestCalc.java

```
import junit.framework.*;

public class TestCalc extends TestCase { 

  protected void setUp() { 

          // put common setup code in here
   }

  protected void tearDown() {

          // put common cleanup code in here
  }

  public void testAddForTest2() {
          int num1 = 3;
          int num2 = 2;
          int total = 5;
          int sum = 0;
          sum = Math.add(num1, num2);
          assertEquals(sum, total);
  }
  public void testsubtractForTest2() {
                  int num1 = 5;
                  int num2 = 2;
                  int total = 3;
                  int sum = 0;
                  sum = Math.subtract(num1, num2);
                  assertEquals(sum, total);
          }


  public void testMulitplyForTest2() {

          int num1 = 3; 
          int num2 = 7; 
          int total = 21;
          int sum = 0;
          sum = Math.multiply(num1, num2);
          assertEquals("Problem with multiply", sum, total);

   }

}
```

//TestMath.java

```
import junit.framework.*;

public class TestMath extends TestCase { 

  protected void setUp() { 

          // put common setup code in here
   }

  protected void tearDown() {

          // put common cleanup code in here
  }

  public void testAdd() {
          int num1 = 3;
          int num2 = 2;
          int total = 5;
          int sum = 0;
          sum = Math.add(num1, num2);
          assertEquals(sum, total);
  }
  public void testsubtract() {
                  int num1 = 5;
                  int num2 = 2;
                  int total = 3;
                  int sum = 0;
                  sum = Math.subtract(num1, num2);
                  assertEquals(sum, total);
          }


  public void testMulitply() {

          int num1 = 3; 
          int num2 = 7; 
          int total = 20;
          int sum = 0;
          sum = Math.multiply(num1, num2);
          assertEquals("Problem with multiply", sum, total);

   }

}
```

Comment: So the question is how to avoid the aggregated report?

Comment: Yes but preserve the other output(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is producing the merged report:

```
            <junitreport todir="${reports.xml.dir}">
                    <fileset dir="${reports.xml.dir}">
                            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
                    </fileset>
            </junitreport>
```

From [`JunitReport`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html):

> Merge the individual XML files generated by the JUnit task and
>   eventually apply a stylesheet on the resulting merged document to
>   provide a browsable report of the testcases results.

Comment: @Sharath Didn't you want to want to eliminate the aggregated report.

Comment: Yes.. but I am still getting the aggregated report.. even after I removed printsummary.. I am expecting 2 xml files, 1 for each testcase written..but the third aggregated report is still present..

Comment: @Sharath Ah! that's because of `<junitreport>`.  See edit above.